# События - Ajax или WebScoket

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Всем привет. Разрабатываю проект на Laravel. Есть идея реализовать события на подобие: пользователь отправил сообщение второму пользователю, если второй пользователь онлайн - отправить ему уведомление. На уме два варианта реализации:
чекать ajax-ом базу с интервалом 5 секунд, и веб-сокет. Сокет нужно держать постоянно открытым, независимо от того на какой странице сейчас пользователь.
Какие ваши идеи? Что лучше использовать?

Comment: Почитайте про long poll. Это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Для таких вещей и придуманы сокеты. Используйте их.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko
У меня один сокет уходит на чат. Второй создать на уведомления? Или же всё обрабатывать в одном сокете - отправлять в json, а там смотреть по типу запроса.

Comment: Да, вполне можно использовать один сокет. Два открывать незачем. Да, смотреть какие данные пришли - сообщение, уведомление или еще что-то.